# Controller method not being called

Tags: forms, laravel-5

I'm having an issue where my Laravel method isn't being called when I submit a form.

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="/contact">
<div class="form__field">
<input id="name" name="name" type="text"><label for="name">Name</label>
</div>
<div class="form__field">
<input id="email" name="email" type="email"><label for="email">Email</label>
</div>
<div class="form__field">
<select id="select-floor" name="select-floor">
<option disabled selected>
I'm interested in floor…
</option>
<option value="basement">
Front house
</option>
<option value="ground-floor">
Ground floor
</option>
<option value="first-floor">
First floor
</option>
<option value="second-floor">
Second floor
</option>
<option value="third-floor">
Third floor
</option>
</select><label class="visually-hidden" for="select-floor">Select floor…</label>
</div>
<div class="form__field">
<textarea name="message"></textarea><label for="message">Message</label>
</div><button class="" type="submit">Send Enquiry</button>
</form>
```

This is my route file:

```
Route::get('/contact', function () {
  return view('pages/contact', [
    'title' => 'Contact',
    'description' => ''
  ]);
});

Route::post('/contact','ContactController@sendEmail');
```

And in my controller I have:

```
class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function sendEmail(){
        dd('test');
    }
}
```

What I am expecting to happen is that the string `test` is outputted and the application should just end. What is actually happening is that form page is just reloading.

I checked the developer console and I can see a 419 error but the page is then displayed instead of the 419 error.

I am completely stumped. What am I missing?

Comment: what version of laravel you use please?

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih it appears to be 5.6.39

Comment: check my response please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out a previous developer had introduced a JavaScript plugin that was intercepting the button action and preventing it from POSTing correctly.

The plugin is no longer maintained so I removed it and my form started working as anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

first of all make sure you have [laravelcollective html](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#installation) package within your project or install it. after that just  edit ur form method  like below:

```
    <form method="post" action="{{ url('/contact') }}">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
```

here you are missed to add csrf token to your form, that why your code does not work correctly. for more information about csrf please read this [csrf owasp](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))

Comment: Even with the CSRF field I am still not triggering my method.

Comment: No error message is outputted. The page is just reloaded.

Comment: you are on prod or dev env?

Comment: I'm running this locally.

Comment: have you enabled reporting error in ur env, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184617/discussion-between-thamer-belfkih-and-burgi).

Answer (score -1):

have you tried replacing

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="/contact">
```

with

```
<form method="POST" class="form" action="{{ route('contact') }}" >
    @csrf
```

Comment: Please try now.